# Sitemap Generation: Update lastmod/last_published_at of Page Manually

Tags: python, django, sitemap, wagtail

I have a `PublicationsPage` and a `PublicationPage` class.
The `PublicationsPage` shows a list of its direct children and renders them in a short preview list at `http://mysite/publications`.

```
class PublicationsPage(Page):
    # ...
    def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        publications = PublicationPage.objects.child_of(self).live()
        context['publications'] = publications
        return context
```

This means whenever a new `PublicationPage` is added/deleted/modified the list updates accordingly. But since I am not updating the `PublicationsPage` the `lastmod`/`last_published_at` attribute of the `/publications` location never changes. Wouldn't this be missleading for a search engine?

---

A really hacky attempt could be to update the `last_published_at` date of the parent page every time I touch a child entry.

```
class PublicationPage(Page):
    # ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        result = super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        from datetime import datetime
        parent_page = self.get_parent()
        parent_page.last_published_at = datetime.now()
        parent_page.save()
        return result
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I'm not an SEO expert, but I don't think there's any expectation that the 'last modified' date in a sitemap has to cover changes to any element of the page, including ones that are not "editorially" part of that page's content. If that were the case, then logically a page with a randomised banner would have to always have a last modified date of 'now'...

Comment: In my case, the ``/publications`` location has no other content than a list of ``PublicationPage`` information. I am not an SEO either but it somehow feels wrong that the ``lastmod`` tag would never change.

Comment: If there's no unique content specific to that page, then presumably there will rarely or never be a situation where it's a useful thing to see in search results - in which case SEO is a bit of a moot point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define [`get_sitemap_urls`](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.4/reference/contrib/sitemaps.html#urls) on your Page model, something like this:

```
class PublicationsPage(Page):
    def get_sitemap_urls(self, request=None):
        # Get the defaults sitemap URLS.
        urls = super().get_sitemap_urls(request=request)

        # Get the last modifications time of your publications.
        publications = PublicationPage.objects.child_of(self).live()
        last_publication = publications.order_by('-last_published_at').first()

        # Update the default entry.
        if last_publication:
            urls[0]['lastmod'] = last_publication.last_published_at

        # Return the urls.
        return urls
```

Answer (score 2):

When generating the [sitemap](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#sitemap-class-reference), you can set the property [`lastmod`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#django.contrib.sitemaps.Sitemap.lastmod), which accepts a method, called for every item of the sitemap.

Therefore, when generating the `PublicationsPage` sitemap, set that property to a method that queries all the children of each `PublicationsPage` item and return the latest date.